# Saving an arbritrary length array in SharedPreferences - Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My objective is to save a field entered in an EditText when the user clicks on a button; in this case it's an IP address. The idea would be to show a list of all valid entered IPs when the user focuses on the EditText, similar to saved searches.

I found this useful piece of code. I need a bit of help explaining it. The code runs putString of all the elements in the `String[] array` which I think is a collection of all the submitted fields in EditText. How do I create this array if only one field is getting added at a time? I need an explanation of what is happening below.

```
public boolean saveArray(String[] array, String arrayName, Context mContext) {   
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();  
    editor.putInt(arrayName +"_size", array.length);  
    for(int i = 0;i < array.length; i++){ 
        editor.putString(arrayName + "_" + i, array[i]);  
    }
    return editor.commit();
}

public String[] loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {  
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
    int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);  
    array = new String[size];  
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  
        array[i] = prefs.getString(arrayName + "_" + i, null);  
    return array;  
}
```

Comment: serialize it to json, save json as a string. When you need to get it, get string and deserialize it to array

Comment: As such? `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); json.put("key","value"); Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); bundle.putString("json", json.toString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement and the code you referenced, **I get the following idea:**

Untested for erratas:

```
public boolean saveoneData(String oneTimeData, String key, Context mContext) {   
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0); 

    int size = prefs.getInt(key+"_size", 0); // For the first time it gives the default value(0)

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); 

    editor.putString(key+ "_" + size, oneTimeData);   
    editor.putInt(key+"_size", ++size);  // Here everytime you add the data, the size increments.


    return editor.commit();
}

public String[] loadArray(String key, Context mContext) {  
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
    int size = prefs.getInt(key+ "_size", 0);  
    array = new String[size];  
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  
        array[i] = prefs.getString(key+ "_" + i, null);  
    return array;  
}
```

But I usually don't use the `sharedpreferences` for large storage of data because it could make `data creation, retrieval and data modifications` difficult as the data increases. Hope this is what you want.

Comment: I plan on only saving 3-5 values. SharedPreferences should be ok for that?

Comment: In my view, 3-5 values doesn't matter at all. It's fine using sharedpreferences as long as you don't store more than 20 or so. Did my answer help?

Comment: Here `editor.putString(key+ "_" + size, array[i]);` array is initially null (nothing saved yet). Does that need to be changed?

Comment: I am sorry, I typed directly here itself. That was why I mentioned it as untested. Edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, let me try to implement it. Thanks

Comment: It works! Now, how do I make sure only 5 are stored in SharedPreferences? I can make the array only 5 elements long but is there a way to restrict the preferences to 5?

Answer (score 1):

Once you collect all `EditText` values in one String[] array or `List<String>` or `Set<String>;`
You don't need to save each array value as separate key-value pair in the SharedPreferences. There is much simpler way to save, which is create `Set<String>` and save them all values under one key:

`editor.putStringSet(arrayName, new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array));`

For retrieving you can retrieve them as `Set<String>` in same manner:

`Set<String> ipsSet = sharedPrefs.getStringSet(arrayName, null);`

`What is happening in the code you posted:`
Each value of String array is saved individually under unique key and the size of the array, likewise.
Similarly later each item is retrieved moving in the range 0 to the `saved size of the array`, which is retrieved at first place from the `SharedPreferences`